# CartoDB First click layer selector doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, cartodb

I'm working on an interactive map using CartoDB built of Leaflet.js. I added a layer selector which works fine after the first click. The first click just doesn't work, if I click the selected layer (Layer 2) it reloads it, but click any other layer and the data is removed from the map, until a second click. Does anyone know the solution for the first click not responding?

The html of the layer selector:

```
<div id="cartocss" class="layer_selector" style="margin-top: -200px; z-index: 100; position: relative; width: 10em; background: white;">
    <p id="js-crime-selector">LAYER SELECTOR</p>
        <ul class="LayerSelector-list">
            <li data="0" class="mt-layer-select">Layer 1
        </li>
            <li data="1" class="mt-layer-select reset-view">Layer 2
        </li>
            <li data="2" class="mt-layer-select route-22">Route 22
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the js detecting the click and creating the selector:

```
var vizjson = 'https://thomvandegeer.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/a8fc004a-b86b-11e5-b7ca-0ecd1babdde5/viz.json';
cartodb.createLayer(map_object, vizjson)
.addTo(map_object)
.done(function(layer) {
    $(".mt-layer-select").on('click', function(e) {
        var num = +$(e.target).attr('data');
        createSelector(layer,num,$(e.target));
    })
    $(".route-22").on('click', function(){
        map_object.setView([52.3665, 4.897], 17, {animation: true});
    })
    $(".reset-view").on('click', function(){
        map_object.setView([52.37, 4.9], 15, {animation: true});
    })
});

function createSelector(layer,num) {
    for (var i = 0; i < layer.getSubLayerCount(); i++) {
        if (i === num) {
            layer.getSubLayer(i).show();
        } else {
            layer.getSubLayer(i).hide();
        }
    }
}
```

**And it's online [here](http://thomvandegeer.com/school/informotion/).**

Thanks!

Comment: Are you still looking for solution or you've changed your mind, as the layer selector doesn't exist on live page anymore

Comment: No, it was just temporarily and used the code in other buttons. Easy access layer selector is back again.